# Odoo 10: production doesn't see real quantity available

Tags: odoo, inventory-management, product-quantity, odoo-10

I'm trying odoo 10 but I have a production problem. I created the products and added the quantity through "Inventory Adjustment" but when I go to create a production order the "quantity available" is always zero (even if on inventory the quantities are correct). Which could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: The question is not about programming and belongs to the Odoo help forum.

Answer (score 0):

If your **product type is consumable** then you must have to **use the stackable** to solve this problem.

> To check your product type you can go to the **Sales -> Product -> 
>   select your product -> and check as shown in below figure.**

[image: Product-Conf-Consumable]